# Google Docs CSV layer in ArcGis doesn't update automatically

Tags: layers, arcgis-online, csv

I have added a layer to ArcGis Online from a Google Docs spreadsheet, following the instruction on this blog post

https://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/02/21/using-google-docs-in-your-arcgis-online-maps/

But the layer doesn't update automatically. Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the refresh interval on the layer within the web map. Check out this doc link. This is important for this to be supported you need to have  CSV file from the web with latitude and longitude fields.

http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/set-refresh-interval.htm